# php change password script tried many diffrent nothing works

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords

I have big troubles to get a script to work for changing password and getting really tired off it so if any in have an ides it would be great.

What I am after is a script that checks what user who is log in and then have 3 field with: old password, new password and repeat password and then simply submit and the password should change in the database.

I use mySQL and this is live on a website so nothing is local

Pleas tell me if you need more information.

this is the code to check connections and log in:

```
    <?php

ob_start();
$host="***"; 
$username="***"; 
$password="***"; 
$db_name="***"; 
$tbl_name="***";


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 


$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1){


session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
$msg = "Du är inloggad!";
header("location:main_login.php?msg=$msg");
}
else {
$msg = "Fel användarnamn eller lösenord!";
header("location:main_login.php?msg=$msg");
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I tried this code and modifyed it a bit but didnt get it to work and dont know what i am doing wrong.
:(

NOTE: no MD5 or other security to password is required

```
<?php
$_SESSION["myusername"];
$conn = mysql_connect("***","***","***");
mysql_select_db("***",$conn);
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *from users WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["myusername"] . "'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {
mysql_query("UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE userId='" . $_SESSION["myusername"] . "'");
$message = "Password Changed";
} else $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Password</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script>
function validatePassword() {
var currentPassword,newPassword,confirmPassword,output = true;

currentPassword = document.frmChange.currentPassword;
newPassword = document.frmChange.newPassword;
confirmPassword = document.frmChange.confirmPassword;

if(!currentPassword.value) {
    currentPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("currentPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
else if(!newPassword.value) {
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("newPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
else if(!confirmPassword.value) {
    confirmPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
if(newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value) {
    newPassword.value="";
    confirmPassword.value="";
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same";
    output = false;
}   
return output;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmChange" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validatePassword()">
<div style="width:500px;">
<div class="message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" class="tblSaveForm">
<tr class="tableheader">
<td colspan="2">Change Password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%"><label>Current Password</label></td>
<td width="60%"><input type="password" name="currentPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="currentPassword"  class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>New Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="newPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="newPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="confirmPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, here's a simple function you could use? Untested but it's written around the use of PDO, you'd have to adapt it a bit, I've not used Mysql for years.

```
function changePassword($previous, $previoustwo, $new, $userid)
{
    if ($previous != $previoustwo) { 
        return false; 
    }
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $hashPass = password_hash($new, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $values = array($hashPass, $userid);
    if ($query->execute($values)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could then call this by doing this for example, perhaps with $_POST data though:

```
changePassword('oldpassword321', 'oldpassword321', 'newawesomepassword123', 11);
```

Comment: will test soon thansk :)

Comment: Remember this is using PDO before you attempt it! :) Also, don't forget to check to see if previous password is the same as their current password before you update it.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like

```
if ($mynewpassword == $mynewpassword2) {
    mysql_query("set password = password('$mynewpassword')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see your mysql error by using this code.

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT *from users WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["myusername"] . "'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {
mysql_query("UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE userId='" . $result["id"] . "'");
$message = "Password Changed";
} else {
$message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
```

Comment: The thing is this is my code to verify loged in users and sql connection dont have any change password code becasue i didnt found anything that worked so i was wounder if someone had something that could work with the code I posted :)

Comment: I have updated my questuion if you wanna take a look.

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'userId' in 'where clause'

My columns are: user_id, username, password

Comment: The problem is you were sending user name instead of user id in where clause. Please check edited message and share the results

Comment: i reach the page these time and the message Password Change was already writen on the page when i wnet to it then i type my old pass and new and it said Current Password is not correct

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

i use this on my pages to check if it have somteing to with that?